# How to detect the number of threads i can & i should run?

Tags: python, multithreading

i have a 6th generation Intel i5 Processor (4 cores, 3 ghZ) and 8 gigabytes of RAM. Let's assume i need to create a text file which includes every number from 0 to 999999999.

How can  i make it faster? How many threads i should use? 4 or more than 4? How many threads i should run and why?

Comment: It'll be IO-bound so more than one wouldn't do much.

Comment: But they will make it at least a little faster, right?

Comment: They'll probably slow it down.

Comment: In Python, Threads are executed on the same core processor, so your computer configuration does not matter much. If you are looking for performance, you should use `multiprocess` instead.

Comment: Okey, thanks. i am testing it now on a Intel Pentium Processor 1.80 ghZ, i will post the results.

Comment: Delgan, thanks. I will search it in a minute.

Comment: @ParanoidPhysicist the question is interesting, but given the fact that you have to write data this may be the operation to focus your performance improvement efforts on.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact you're writing into the same file, you will need a lock in order for the text not to get garbled. If you're using a lock however, multi-threading or multi-processing won't make a difference as it will be writing sequentially.

Not using a lock will get a result much like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 54,, ...
```

as one thread will write it's own and the other thread will write at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

because of GIL you should use multiprocessing module. number of process should be:

```
multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1 # -1 for other system process.
```

Comment: This is really a *guess*, my *guess* is that using just one process will be faster, as it will probably be IO-bound and using one process avoids the overhead/waits of locking the output file, but I could be wrong. Don't assume, **test**!

Comment: @Carpetsmoker numbers between 0 and 999999999 can be saved in list and write in file at once!

Comment: But is that actually faster? That's another *guess* ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, the question has two parts. making faster and best number of threads. i answered second part! my experience has shown that python loops for big numbers is very very slow, so i think using multiprocessing is better...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers & comments. I couldn't try the multiprocessing module because i am on a vacation and my computer has 2 cores, it would be the same (1 for system, 1 for python.). But i will add the results with the multiprocessing as soon as i get home. So, here is my test results with a Intel Pentium Dual Core 1.80ghZ:

Without extra threads it took 4 seconds.
With one extra thread it took 3 seconds.

After the second thread it didn't change. I tried with 3, 4 and 5 threads, every time it took 3 seconds.

Here are the codes;

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23098237/ > 1 thread

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23098229/ > 2 thread

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23098131/ > 3 thread

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23098136/ > 4 thread

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23098139/ > 5 thread

sorry, i couldn't paste the code here, it said "not properly formatted as code". i tried for like 10 minutes, (ctrl + k, 4 spaces) it didn't work, so i just posted it on paste.ubuntu.com